# more than one popup - Maximum call stack size exceeded - jQuery Error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have popup with some html and delete button. On delete button click, Dialog box is open and i got

> "**Uncaught RangeError:** Maximum call stack size exceeded - jQuery Error"

```
$("body").delegate('.delete','click',function(e){
        BootstrapDialog.confirm('Are you sure you want to remove this post?', function(e,result){
            alert("HI");
     });
    } 
});
```

can anyone give me feasible solution?

Comment: There is too much `}`

Comment: The use of `delegate()` suggests you're using a *very* outdated version of jQuery which you should update ASAP.

Comment: I already used .on method also but it is still not working $("body").on('click','.delete',function(e){
        BootstrapDialog.confirm('Are you sure you want to remove this post?', function(e,result){
            alert("HI");
     });
    } 
});

Answer (score 1):

You may have multiple items that uses class `.delete`. You can use a id instead of class

```
$("#delete").on("click",function(){
  BootstrapDialog.confirm('Are you sure you want to remove this post?', function(e,result){
            alert("HI");
});
```